# Encrypting sms by a java app

Tags: java, eclipse, sms

IS it possible to encrypt and then send the  sms to a gateway like txtweb.com .I want to develop a JAVA banking application which uses the inbuilt sms sending feature of a phone.
Since bank app has money transfers i want to encrypt the sms.Is it possible to to recieve  sms replies by the gateway in the MIDlet itself.

Comment: Thank you Roshanlal..can u suggest a better encryption algorithm.i am newbie to J2ME so can u please give some details.

Comment: Glad to have helped you! Please see my updated answer for the details you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible and assuming that you are using J2ME, you should be able to use the in-built Messaging classes to send/receive the text messages.

As for encrypting, process the text as you would a normal `String`. For example, if you decide to use ROT13 encryption, you could take the text `char` by `char` and increment each by 13. Then after the encryption is done, just set the message load to the text you just processed, and then use the in-built functions of the Messaging classes of J2ME.

**EDIT**

More resources about sending/receiving SMS, encyption algorithms and J2ME development as have been requested are provided below. And you may want to take a look at [Oracle J2ME Docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/documentation/index.html) also.

For more about encryption and different data encryption algorithms: [Encryption - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)

For code snippet of sending/receiving SMS in J2ME: [SMS Sending/Receiving Code Snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5115)

For beginning J2ME Development: [Beginning J2ME - From Novice To Professional 3rd Edition](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/beginningj2me)

Comment: thanks once again.What do u think about using Quasigroups Cryptographic algorithms(QCA) anyway i will review my project and see how it can be done.

Comment: @SumatejaKonge I'm not much familiar with encryption algorithms and my area of expertise is J2ME.. So can't help you here, but good luck with your project! :)